# Find element at (x,y) coordinate in Javascript (highest visible element)

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an HTML debugger with pure Javascript and I'm come to a roadblock while trying to emulate a mouse pointer. The idea is to move the mouse on an "admin" page and the change will be reflected on the client machine running the debug Javascript code. I want to "click" on the admin page and target the client DOM element that the simulated cursor on the client machine is under for css/remove operations. So I can calculate which element is under the image using z-index, DOM order, etc but that puts a huge load on the client and the point is to keep this application as lite as possible. Plus, the browser is already doing those calculations for the mouse and it would be a waste to rewrite the entire algorithm myself(If I have the time and patience).

**Is there a javascript function or are there browser specific api's that I can use to determine what element is directly under another?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) should work for you. If you want all the elements at an (x, y) coordinate, there are a number of implementations of an `elementsFromPoint`, e.g. https://gist.github.com/oslego/7265412.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}, false);
```

Comment: The mouse cursor is just an image on the client side, I can't attach a mouse event to it.

Comment: I thought you were, with something like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: I don't want to fire an actual click event since permissions are js touch events. I want to click on the admin page, generate a dialog in the context of the clients side DOM element that the mouse image is over.